# Скачать сайт через php (для парсинга) со всем текстовым содержимым

Tags: php, парсер, curl, simple-html-dom

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь сделать парсер для новостных - экономических сайтов, и на этом  сайте у меня глохнет: 
http://ir.debenhams.com/news-releases.

С него я пытаюсь вытащить табличку, которая на него загружается с этого сайта http://tools.eurolandir.com/tools/pressreleases/?companycode=uk-deb&lang=en-gb, а там эта таблица подгружается с помощью ajax зпроса. 
Проблема в том, что при запросе страницы с помощью simple dom html, таблицы в нём нету. Пытался использовать curl, чтобы загружать все, но то ли не все верные параметры задал, то ли руки кривы.
Не грузится данные, даже если напрямую со второго сайта пытаться качать.

 Подскажите пожалуйста, хотя бы в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Там подгрузка скорее всего происходит через `ajax`.

Comment: Вы правы, ошибся. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Никак этого не сделать. Точнее сделать можно, но сложно.
Гораздо проще с помощью php грузить http://tools.eurolandir.com/tools/pressreleases/?companycode=uk-deb&lang=en-gb и уже ответ с этого адреса парсить.

Comment: Так проблема в том, что даже при попытки грузить сразу со второго сайта полностью не грузиться из-за его внутреннего автозаполнения.

Comment: Вы можете сделать парсинг страницы, в `iframe`, а уже из фрейма получить нужную информацию.

Comment: Проблема та в том, что парсить не чего. Я не могу достать данные из таблицы даже если качать напрямую страницу из iframe, т.к. они формируются динамически по средствам ajax запросов.

Comment: Прочитайте мой коммент. пока не поймете.

Comment: @And Я кажется понял, но все равно не работает. Я пытался лезть на внутренний сайт и его парсить, а можно просто  $html = file_get_html('http://ir.debenhams.com/news-releases');

foreach($html->find('iframe') as $iframe) {
echo $iframe->outertext, PHP_EOL;
} Так?

Comment: Но этот же метод работает на других сайтах с iframe, которые я должен парсить.

Comment: Это нужно через js делать, парсить на фрейме, а дальше тащить и отправлять на сервер. Сервер ничего не знает о клиенте, а это значит он не увидет ajax запрос на данном сайте.

Comment: А в чем проблема самому выполнить POST запрос, который получает данные таблицы и получить эти данные в виде JSON'a?

Comment: Единоразово это сделать полагаю не проблема, но как автоматизировать чтобы на каждом подобном сайте проводились все POST запросы с правильными параметрами, потом находился нужный  из них JSON (в котором содержаться нужная мне таблица) я не знаю.

Comment: Ну на каждом подобном вряд ли получится, конечно. Т.к. параметры везде разные, единственное что вы можете - это поиграться с апи и выяснить какими параметрами формируется запрос, чтобы довольно легко было его составлять для конкретного сайта. А в общем случае я бы посоветовал вам обратится к скриптовым браузерам SlimerJS/PhantomJS. Вот пример материала на хабре https://habr.com/post/247847/

Comment: Используйте phantomjs, например, и какую-нибудь php-либу для взаимодействия с ним (типа http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/ или свою напишите).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если контент страницы создаётся с помощью js, то придётся выполнить js, чтобы получить тот HTML, который вы наблюдаете в браузере. Специально для задач автоматизации есть браузер без графического интерфейса -- [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Вот простой способ попробовать его в деле:

Запустим phantomjs в [докер-контейнере](https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/).

```
docker run -d -p 8910:8910 wernight/phantomjs phantomjs --webdriver=8910
```

Теперь у вас на `localhost:8910` есть вебдрайвер-интерфейс, на который удобно ходить с помощью библиотеки [php-webdriver](https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/webdriver), например.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$driver = \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create(
    'localhost:8910',
    \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::phantomjs()
);
$driver->get('http://tools.eurolandir.com/tools/pressreleases/?companycode=uk-deb&lang=en-gb');
sleep(2); // жду чтобы js отработал, но вы можете нагуглить более правильные способы сделать это
$html = $driver->getPageSource();

echo $html;
```

Если вы пока ещё не разобрались как использовать докер, то можете установить phantomjs в свою систему и работать с ним с помощью библиотек типа [jonnyw/php-phantomjs](https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyw/php-phantomjs) (она кажется даже умеет сама установить phantomjs).

Comment: Сделал в итоге через библиотеку php-phantomjs. Сработало для похожей ссылки http://www.highlandgold.com/home/investors/regulatory-news/, у которой тотже источник заполнения для iframe, но к сожалению почему-то для этой не дало результата http://ir.debenhams.com/news-releases, качает всё, но незаполненное текстом( Есть может какие идеи или рекомендации по использования библиотеки? Я пробовал ставить Lazy мод и ожидание 12 секунд ставить.

Comment: @КонстантинПетров там же _iframe_. Родитель не может получить доступа к содержимому iframe, если там загружен документ с другого домена. Воспринимайте iframe как отдельное окно (вкладку браузера). Ваш паук может просто обрабатывать фрэймы как ссылки, то есть вам надо парсить страницу указанную в `src`.

Comment: Я так и попробовал. На примере этих двух сайтов я скачивал через PhantomJS данные по ссылке из iframe. Но тут и появилась странность сайты ссылаются на https://tools.eurolandir.com/tools/pressreleases/?companycode=uk-hgm&lang=en-gb и https://tools.eurolandir.com/tools/pressreleases/?companycode=uk-deb&lang=en-gb соответсвенно, что вроде один сайт, но первая ссылка скачивается полностью, а вот вторая с незаполненными div элементами (а мне они и нужны).  Подскажите пожалуйста, если есть идеи, в чём между ними разница?

Comment: @КонстантинПетров как вы убеждаетесь что элементы пусты? Я сейчас попробовал, у меня нормально скачались обе ссылки. Возможно у вас не успевает отработать js (у меня 2 секунд хватает)?

Comment: Я для проверки качал по началу в файл и смотрел в ручную что качает, сюда код выложил. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898286/phantomjs-php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-iframe