# PhantomJs PHP загрузка из iframe

Tags: php, парсер, phantomjs

Всем привет!
Я пытаюсь сделать автоматический парсер для группы сайтов, для этого использую phatomJs-PHP. 
При попытки скачать данные из iframe-ов этих двух сайтов http://www.highlandgold.com/home/investors/regulatory-news/ и https://investors.inmarsat.com/regulatory-news/ с первым всё работает, а у второго все div элементы качаются без текста. Это при том, что оба сайта грузят данные для этих фреймов из одного источника.
Качаю так:

```
$client = Client::getInstance();
$path = 'vendor\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe';   
$client->getEngine()->setPath($path);
$client->isLazy();
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--load-images=false');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--ignore-ssl-errors=true');
$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest($startUrl, 'GET');
$request->setTimeout(5000);
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
$client->send($request, $response);
if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    $cont = $response->getContent();
    file_put_contents($name.'.xml', $startUrl.$cont);
    $html = str_get_html($cont);
    return $html;
} else{
    echo '<br> ERROR JONNY: '.$response->getStatus();
}
```

Ошибок никаких не выводит, просто там где должен быть текст (таблица с ссылками и датами) - пусто.
Пожалуйста объясните где я облажался.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, этот код получает содержимое (`getContent`) сразу после загрузки страницы. При этом js может ещё не отработать, попробуйте добавить `sleep(2);` перед `$response->getContent();`

Comment: К сожалению setTimeout(5000) по идеи уже ставит 5 секунд ожидания, но даже с дополнительными двумя sleep(2) не заработало. А вы пробовали через запуск в докере? Если да, то пойду наверно лучше по нему читать, а то я уже перепробовал десятки вариантов для загрузки через библиотеки php и пока нечего не работало(

Comment: Насколько я понимаю `setTimeout` задаёт время ожидания ответа от сервера, а не время ожидания после загрузки страницы. Да, я использовал докер и вебдрайвер.

Comment: Кажется я разобрался (но это не точно), вам надо использовать `setDelay`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так (обратите внимание, я убрал `isLazy` и добавил `setDelay`):

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$startUrl = 'https://tools.eurolandir.com/tools/pressreleases/?companycode=uk-deb&lang=en-gb';

$client = Client::getInstance();
$path = __DIR__ . '/vendor/bin/phantomjs';   
$client->getEngine()->setPath($path);
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--load-images=false');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--ignore-ssl-errors=true');
$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest($startUrl, 'GET');
$request->setDelay(5);
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
$client->send($request, $response);
if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    echo $response->getContent();
} else{
    echo '<br> ERROR JONNY: '.$response->getStatus();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё сработало. Похоже isLazy действительно отменял setDelay.