# "Ходилка" по сайту

Tags: php, парсер

Есть сайт aviasales.

Мне нужно знать самое дешевое направление по тому или иному маршруту на определенную дату.

У них есть бесплатное [АПИ](https://support.travelpayouts.com/hc/ru/articles/203956163-Travelpayouts-API-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B#02).

Есть метод, который мне полностью подходит. (*Возвращает список цен, найденных нашими пользователями за последние 48 часов, в соответствии с выставленными фильтрами.*)
Однако, если никто по какому-то маршруту не производил поиск, то значит данный метод не вернет мне ничего. 
Т.е., чтобы данный маршрут появился в этом методе необходимо просто произвести по нему поиск (перейти по ссылке типа: https://www.aviasales.ru/search/KZN2601MOW30012)/ После чего я через АПИ уже смогу получить цену.

Сейчас я просто запустил программу zennoPoster, которая ежедневно прогуливается по заданным url. Но этот подход мне не нравится, т.к. компьютер постоянно должен быть запущен. Арендовать где-то windows машину дорого.

Если на php, то просто вызов file_get_contents не даст результата, потому что подгрузка идет javascript-ом. Вычислять последовательность, т.е. искать, что делает внутри сам авиасейлс и к каким url обращается долго и ненадежно, т.к. алгоритм всегда может непредсказуемо поменяться.

Какие варианты этого решения еще могут быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Не совсем понятно - вам не нравится решение с постоянно запущенным компьютером. Но чтобы тоже-самое работало на php - нужен точно такой-же постоянно запущенный компьютер, сервер. Если вам интересно как это сделать на php - надо использовать curl с опциями `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` и `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`. Тогда через курл очень просто эмулируется хождение по страницам как в браузере - работая с куками. Только может не подойти, если на сайте есть дополнительная защита от такого: например грузится однопиксельная картинка-маяк, или же из глухо обфусцированного js делается запрос-маяк.

Comment: Писал же "Арендовать где-то windows машину дорого."
Есть средства только на линукс

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам может помочь [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org). Для php есть [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) фэйсбука.

В [похожем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897071/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC) писал рецепт использования php-webdriver c phantomjs. Разработку phantomjs вроде свернули и сейчас вместо него используют headless chrome (суть приблизительно та же).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется в данной ситуации было бы удобным решение взять обычный php хостинг с поддержкой крона, и на нем повесить на крон с нужной периодичностью скрипт, который будет выполнять необходимые действия. Если для того, чтобы сформировались нужные данные достаточно просто сходить по урлу, то тогда для этого будет достаточно использовать curl, и затем уже получить данные и сделать с ними необходимые манипуляции.

Для более изощренной работы с сайтами можно использовать, как сказано выше? php-webdriver.

Но в любом случае будьте готовы к тому, что может возникнуть необходимость что то поправить в алгоритме получения данных для любого выбранного решения, т.к. может измениться как верстка на сайте, так и логика его работы, и придется свое решение адаптировать к этим изменениям.

Comment: не думаю что php-webdriver сработает на "обычный php хостинг", для его работы в системе нужен GUI что бы запускать браузеры в которых будет происходить работа

Comment: Если дело дойдет до использования  Селениума, то да, тут придется искать другое решение, например виртуальный сервер или облако, а если просто curl-ом обойтись можно, то тут виртуального хостинга с поддержкой curl и cron будет более чем достаточно.

Comment: А толку от крона. Там подгрузка идет javascript-ом.
Можете зайти на сайт авиасейлс.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю , работа с сокетами на php это слезы и боль (пробовал парсить яндекс недвижимость) , поэтому советую посмотреть в сторону **python** и scrapy соответственно ! А так - эмулировать браузер, как писали **коллеги выше**